# BigQuery streaming data not available instantly

Tags: google-bigquery

Since couple of days some data i am streaming to bigquery is not available instantly (as it normally happens) within bigquery web ui after being inserted successfully.

My use case consists of inserting thousand of lines using :

```
bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(...)
```

The results of the streaming inserts into the table are : 
(i am also checking for insertErrors to be sure as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#troubleshooting)):

```
BigQuery insert status : {"kind":"bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse"}
BigQuery insert errors  : null
```

Total number of lines available in bigquery web ui is different that total inserted.

I would be grateful for any help.

Bigquery project details :

```
Project ID  : favorable-beach-87616
Table : mtp_UA_xxxx_1_20150410
```

Project dependencies on google libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-servlet:1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev171-1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc'
```

Great thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say the total number of lines available in the web UI, do you mean the number of rows that show up in the 'details' pane on the table, or the number of rows that are returned if you do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query?

If the former, that is expected, since that counter only returns the number of rows that have been flushed to long-term storage (as opposed to the short-term storage buffers the streaming data originally gets written to). This is admittedly confusing, and we are working on a fix.

If the latter, the rows don't show up in a query, that is more concerning. If that is the case, please let us know and we'll investigate.

Comment: I am talking about total number of lines i get with "SELECT COUNT(*)" query. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem, I use Python insertAll() to streaming data into tables, once I dump the data to the table (return successful) I can't see the data using web UI, but if I run a query to query the destination table, it return the rows I inserted, just doesn't show on web UI and table summary (the table summary says 0 rows in that table)

Comment: @CharlesChow - please file a different question; I only accidentally saw your comment while searching for something else.